# Change javascript variable on others script outcome

Tags: javascript, html

I need a way where I can change the variable of a jave script function on the outcome of a different function which gets executed on a input click.

Example of the input:

```
<input type="image" value="74" onclick="WeaponType(this);GetDamage(74);return false;" class="CompactPistol" src=".\Weapons\Bornheim_No_3_Extended.png" alt="Bornheim No.3 Extended">
<span style="color:whitesmoke">Bornheim No. 3 Extended</span>
```

(I could also change the 'GetDamage' function input to 'this' instead of the value directly and then just change the function output to use the attribute 'value'. In my case it doesn't really matter as the value of one picture is set.)

My script that needs the variable currently looks like this:

```
    <script id="ResultDamage">
        function GetDamage(x) {
            document.getElementById("DamageDealt").innerHTML = x;
        }
    </script>
```

This ofc only outputs the value of the function. But the value needs to be used in a more complicated calculation

What I f.e. also already tried was this:

```
    <script id="ResultDamage">
        function GetDamage(x) {
            var z
            z = x;
            return z;
        }
        var d = z;
        document.getElementById("DamageDealt").innerHTML = d;
    </script>
```

and this:

```
    <script id="ResultDamage">
        function GetDamage(x) {
            return x;
        }
        var d = GetDamage();
        document.getElementById("DamageDealt").innerHTML = d;
    </script>
```

Which gives me 'undefined'

Any help is appreciated. 
As I am quite new to this keeping it simple would probably the best (if there is a simple solution)

Comment: The two examples you give at the end don't make much sense.  All the function ever does there is return the value you send it, which is information you already had.  It looks like the original function already updates the `DamageDealt` HTML element, which is what the later examples appear to be trying to do, so what exactly is the issue?  What additional functionality are you trying to add?

Comment: So in the end I want to have a calculation which uses the GetDamage value divides it with a different value for which I need to make a function then multiplies it with two more values and all those values need to come from a function which decides what value needs to be used.

So in short the calculation would look like this:
a/b*c*d

And all the variables in the function are updating depending on its input

Comment: Why can't that calculation happen within the original `GetDamage` function?  Currently that function successfully receives a value and writes it to the page.  Just put the calculation in there so it receives the value, performs the calculation, and writes the result to the page?

Comment: In that case my GetDamage function would have four inputs (a,b,c,d)
Is there a way that one input field can be not used of a input tag?

Comment: Do you just mean that any time this function is invoked you need to use the values of more than one `<input>`?

Comment: So that I have 
```
input1: onclick="GetDamage(1, empty, empty, empty)
input2: onclick="GetDamage(empty, 2, empty, empty)
input3: onclick="GetDamage(empty, empty, 3, empty)
input4: onclick="GetDamage(empty, empty, empty, 4)
```

So my base Idea was. I have multiple functions. That all return an invidual value depending on the users input.
And those values then get used to finish the colculation and output its result

Comment: So then you need to store the *order* in which the inputs are clicked?  Rather than perform the calculation on each click?

Comment: No not really. I need to store the value from the input that gets clicked. Not the order in which they get clicked

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments on the question above...

If you just need to store a value globally on the page then you can declare a variable outside of the function and set its value within any function.  For example:

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
// etc.

function GetDamage(x) {
    a = x;
    // perform a calculation as needed
    // write a result to the page as needed
}
```

In this case the values of `a` and `b` are stored at the page level and available to other functions, persist their values between function calls, etc.  So you can have separate functions that also use those values for their own calculations.

Comment: This looks like what I need yes. But when I tried it the result didn't use the updated numbers. (I sitll want to keep it simple on here so I don't use calculations yet in my function.

My functions now look like this:
`   <script id="ResultDamage">
        var a = 1;
     var b = 1;
   function GetDamage(x) {
    a = x;}
      function BodyPartHit(y) {
    b = y;
   }
  document.getElementById("DamageDealt").innerHTML = a / b;
    </script>`

But the out put is only a / b but a and b don't update on the given input

Comment: @FabFab: Because in that code you're only writing the output once, when the page loads.  You're not updating it in the functions.  Move that line of code to within the functions.  Or make it its own function that's called from within the functions.  Any way you do it, in order to update the output you need to call that operation again.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. This now works and looks promising.I am sure I can get to the needed result with that. Thank you for the patience :D